# Discord.JS: Bot won't stay online, client.once code is stuck

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been recently having issues pop up with my Discord.js bot hosted on repl.it (link is https://replit.com/@anonymouspers27/discordbot#central.js)

The bot worked fine for months. But suddenly, the bot essentially refuses to run. Every time I run `npm start`, the bot gets stuck on the following code:

(line 31, central.js)

```
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('JToH Bot has logged in (loginsuccesful = true)')
});
```

Now, this section of the code just stopped working. The client is always jut stuck. I've tried basically everything I could find, such as trying to update the code (as it hadn't been updated for a while), but even when I did that, the same problems arised. Nothing has worked so far, and no errors appear in the console, which makes this issue much harder to research on.

I'm positive that the issue must be the code becoming outdated, which I am completely unaware of. I still haven't been able to pinpoint any other spots in the code that causes this problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bot gets stuck" on that line of code? If you just mean that the `ready` handler isn't executing, it's probably not an issue with your code at all. This sort of issue is often due to hosting on Replit, especially if you're not seeing any errors. Because thousands of discord bots are hosted on Replit, often with multiple users' bots running on the same shared virtual server (with shared IPs), it is very easy for Replit bots to run into rate limit (they're IP-based) issues or to be unable to login to Discord for a while. Happens all the time, with no console errors.

Comment: One thing you could do is wait a day or two, then try running your discord bot code on your computer instead of Replit and see if it works then. If it does, the issue probably was exactly what I described in the above comment. If not, it will be somewhat difficult to find out what the issue is. If the issue was what I described, the problem will fix itself after a few days.

Comment: By the term 'bot getting stuck', yes, I do mean the handler isn't executing, sorry for the bad wording. Thanks for the tips, I do still have all the files stored locally, so I can see if running it on my computer works.